# Trying to pull all emails from a folder but it stops at 1000

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to read through every email in one of my folders in outlook. For some reason, based off of my counter that I set up, it will only pull up to 1000 emails. Why is this? I initialized my ItemView with int.MaxValue as well. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Well it would be helpful if you showed the code...

Comment: Have you read the documentation? EWSFindCountLimit is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-throttling-in-exchange

Comment: Explicit guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-perform-paged-searches-by-using-ews-in-exchange